# Question about Three-Phase Breaker bloc in Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

The Voltage Measurement block 'Three-Phase V-I Measurement' is connected between two isolated networks. For a valid measurement, the positive and negative terminals of the block must be connected to electrical nodes that are part of the same electrical circuit. Also check if the ground reference node is defined for that circuit.

I get this error when, in my matlab simulink simulation, I place a three-phase breaker block between the three-phase V-I measurement block and the asynchronous machine block, knowing that the measurement block is connected via its input terminals to the inverter block that supplies the motor.
I'd like to use the three-phase breaker block to simulate a phase loss in my system.

Can anyone help me?

Sincerely